# Unable to load canvas elements in correct order using LoadDataFromJSON fabricjs method

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm making an application that allows users to create designs to personalize cards. To do this, I initialize the canvas with a series of guidelines and a white rectangle and then I load the design data.

I use `fabric.Canvas#toJSON` to serialize the canvas and `fabric.Canvas#loadFromJSON` to de-serialize it.

The problem comes when I try to de-serialize the JSON: the 'z-index' position of the objects changes and, therefore, the design rendered is not the original one.

```
function initCanvasFromJson(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        ...
    }).done(function (data) {
        let img_content = JSON.parse(data);
        addGuideLines(canvas);
        canvas.loadFromJSON(img_content ,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));           
    })
}


function addGuideLines(canvas){
        var white_rect = new fabric.Rect({
            width: 636,
            height: 406,
            selectable: false,
            fill: 'white',
            evented: false,
            rx: 10,
            ry: 10,
            name: 'white_rect',
            excludeFromExport: true
        });

        canvas.add(white_rect);
        canvas.centerObject(white_rect);

        var external_border = new fabric.Rect({
            width: 636,
            height: 406,
            selectable: false,
            fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
            stroke: '#5e6462',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            rx: 10,
            ry: 10,
            evented: false,
            name: 'external_border',
            excludeFromExport: true
        });

        canvas.add(external_border);
        canvas.centerObject(external_border);

        var internal_border = new fabric.Rect({
            width: external_border.get('width') - 14.57 + 2,
            height: external_border.get('height') - 14.57 + 2,
            selectable: false,
            fill: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 0.5,
            strokeDashArray: [3, 2],
            rx: 10,
            ry: 10,
            evented: false,
            name: 'internal_border',
            excludeFromExport: true
        });

        canvas.add(internal_border);
        canvas.centerObject(internal_border);

        //We have to keep the guidelines above the rest elements, but the white rect needs to stay in the back.
        canvas.on('object:added', function (e) {
            white_rect.bringToFront();
            external_border.bringToFront();
            internal_border.bringToFront();
            white_rect.sendToBack();
        });

        canvas.renderAll();
    }
```

Debugging the callback inside loadFromJSON method, I discovered that the array of elements has been reverse reordered.

Doing some tests, I realized that if I serialized all the elements inside the canvas (including the white rect and the guidelines), I get to render the design propertly.

Do you have any explanation on why this is happening?

Comment: Use background and foreground image, instead of bringing /sending to back

Comment: you no need to call `addGuideLines(canvas);` inside `done` callback, as all objects will be in your `img_content` json. and I guess `canvas_a.renderAll` it must be `canvas.renderAll` as `canvas_a` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you very much! Instead, I called addGuideLines(canvas) inside the callback of loadFromJSON method and that did the trick.